# Конвертирование строки char* в байт код. Превратить hexdump "89 C2" в байты {0x89, 0xC2}

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Добрый день, подскажите, как преобразовать строку вида:

```
UCHAR bytes[] = "89 C2 48 89 F9 E8 CE 55";
```

В массив байт:

```
UCHAR bytes[] = {0x89,0xC2,0x48,0x89,0xF9,0xE8,0xCE,0x55}
/*UCHAR bytes[] = "\x89\xC2\x48\x89\xF9\xE8\xCE\x55";*/
```

пояснение:

т.е мне нужна функция, на входе которой подается строка (массив символов) - сигнатура массива байт и она преобразуется в массив байт , т.е. 89 это не символы 8 и 9, а HEX код символа '‰' , (HEX)C2 = (INT)62 ='В' и т.д.

Comment: строковой функцией `replace`

Comment: Добавляете в начало пробел, а потом все пробелы заменяете на "\\x"

Comment: В редакторе кода, или програмно?

Comment: програмно, т.е мне нужна функция, на входе которой подается строка (массив символов) - сигнатура массива байт и она преобразуется в массив байт , т.е. 89 это не символы 8 и 9, а HEX код символа '‰' , [1] = -62 'В' и т.д.

Comment: @LuckyGamerTV: Какое еще `-62`? В С++ нет никакого `UCHAR`, но подозреваю, что это `unsigned char`, Т.е. результат у вас *беззнаковый*.

Comment: Хотите вы этого или нет, но ваше преобразование сделать не возможно один к одному. Массив сделать можно, но длинна его или *сохранится* (будет в 3 р больше), или будет *неопределена*, или нужно задействовать класс массива.

Answer (score 5):

В одну строчку :)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
  const char str[] = "89 C2 48 89 F9 E8 CE 55";
  unsigned char bytes[256];

  unsigned char *e = std::copy(std::istream_iterator<unsigned>(std::istringstream(str) >> std::hex), std::istream_iterator<unsigned>(), bytes);

  std::copy(bytes, e, std::ostream_iterator<unsigned>(std::cout << std::hex, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

или, с `std::vector` в качестве получателя

```
const char str[] = "89 C2 48 89 F9 E8 CE 55";
std::vector<unsigned char> bytes;

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<unsigned>(std::istringstream(str) >> std::hex), std::istream_iterator<unsigned>(), std::back_inserter(bytes));
```

---

В качестве побочного замечания можно обратить внимание на то, что

```
std::istream_iterator<unsigned>(std::istringstream(str))
```

является некорректным выражением (из-за того, что конструктор `std::istream_iterator` принимает неконстантную ссылку), а вот

```
std::istream_iterator<unsigned>(std::istringstream(str) >> std::hex)
```

уже вполне корректно. Некоторые правила языка С++ временами приводят к внешне нелогичным результатам...

Comment: наивное переписывание в две строчки (чтобы имена добавить) [ломает этот код](https://ideone.com/SJDrR1)

Comment: @jfs: Конечно. Этот код живет именно за счет однострочности. Для переписывания в две строчки придется всенепременно дать имя стриму.

Comment: причём именно самому istringstream, а не результату `>>hex`. [В три строчки работает](https://ideone.com/1TAMVR)

Comment: @jfs: Да, результату `>> hex` действительно трудно, ибо он уже "деградировал" до `std::basic_istream`... Извернуться, наверное, как-то можно, но лень...

Comment: `unsigned char bytes[256];` — атата! Вместите корректное вычисление размера в одну строчку?

Comment: @VladD: Во-первых, на текущий момент размер на самом деле является частью условия задачи. Я его изменил только ради того, чтобы продемонстрировать использование возвращаемого значения `std::copy`. Во-вторых, заменить на `std::vector` с `std::back_inserter` никакого труда не составит. Но по вопросу не ясно, устроит ли автора `std::vector`. В-третьих, вычисление размера массива в compile time средствами С++11 тоже труда не составит.

Comment: @AnT: Ну, у вас получается немного странное условие, по которому входная строка имеет право меняться, при этом не меняя свой размер :) Я бы на вашем месте всё же заменил на универсальное решение, поскольку код будет копипаститься, и небольшое внешне безобидное изменение условия приведёт к печальным последствиям.

Answer (score 2):

Ну например так:

```
char s[] = "89 C2 48 89 F9 E8 CE 55";
std::vector<UCHAR> result;
std::istringstream iss(s);
unsigned b;
while (iss >> std::hex >> b)
    result.push_back(b);
```

Если нужен именно массив, то придётся подсчитать длину вручную:

```
char s[] = "89 C2 48 89 F9 E8 CE 55";
size_t len = (std::strlen(s) + 1) / 3; // или sizeof(s) / sizeof(*s), если это таки массив,
UCHAR* result = new UCHAR[len];        // а не указатель
std::istringstream iss(s);
unsigned b;
UCHAR* p = result;
while (iss >> std::hex >> b)
    *p++ = b;
```

Comment: Может автор имеет ввиду в редакторе кода?

Comment: @nick_n_a: Может, а бог его знает. Я предположил, что нужно именно распарсить хекс-дамп.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал вот такое чудо ^_^, но работает как часы

```
byte* CharToByte(char* str_sign_WithSpace, int& sizeOfByteArray)
{
printf("strlen_do = %llu\n",strlen(str_sign_WithSpace));    

//Прогоняем строку на пробелы, вырезаем все спеймы (trim all space)
char str_sign[256];
int ij = 0;
do
{
    if (*str_sign_WithSpace != ' ')
    {
        str_sign[ij] = *str_sign_WithSpace;
        ij++;
    }
} while (*str_sign_WithSpace++);

printf("strlen_posle = %llu\n", strlen(str_sign));

unsigned char* ret_ByteArray = new unsigned char[strlen(str_sign)/2];
char** mass_char = new char*[strlen(str_sign)/2];
for (int i(0); i < strlen(str_sign) / 2; i++)
    mass_char[i] = new char[3]{0};

for (int i(0), j(0); i < strlen(str_sign) / 2; i++, j += 2)
{
    if(*(str_sign + j) !='x' || *(str_sign + j) != 'X')
    strncpy(mass_char[i], str_sign + j, 2);
    else
    strncpy(mass_char[i], "00", 2);
    mass_char[i] += '\0';
}

for (int i(0); i < strlen(str_sign) / 2; i++)
{
    printf("mass_CHAR[%i] = %s\n", i, mass_char[i]);
    ret_ByteArray[i] = strtol(mass_char[i],&mass_char[i],16);
    printf("mass_byte[%i]=%X\n", i, ret_ByteArray[i]);
}   
sizeOfByteArray = strlen(str_sign)/2;
delete[] mass_char;
return ret_ByteArray;
}
```

Ну и для проверочки:

```
char* str_sign_Space = "48xxxxxxxxxxxx48xxxxxxxxxxxx75xx48xxxxxxxxxxxxF6xxxxxxxxxxxx74xxF3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx83xxxxxxxxxxxx76xxF3xxxxxxxxxx80xxxxxxxxxxxx74xx80xxxxxxxxxxxx74xxF3xxxxxxxxxxF3xxxxxxxx"; //Строка
int size;
byte* MyByteArray = CharToByte(str_sign_Space, size);

for (int i(0); i < size; i++)   
    printf("%X", MyByteArray[i]);

delete[] MyByteArray;
system("pause");
return 0;
```

В функции присутствует удаление пробелов и замена xx || XX в сигнатуре на 0.

Comment: Часто повторяется `mass_char[i] += '\0';`? В чем вы видите смысл сего бессмысленного действия?

Comment: почему бессмысленного ? а как же конец строки? если его не будет, то после 2х байт будет куча мусора.

Comment: Этот код не имеет никакого отношения к "концу строки". С чего бы это? Это код эквивалентен просто `mass_char[i] += 0;`, то есть вы увеличиваете значение указателя `mass_char[i]` на `0`. От увеличения на `0` значение указателя `mass_char[i]`, разумеется, не меняется. Т.е. действие совершенно бессмысленное - оно ничего не делает вообще.

Comment: `mass_char[i] = new char[3]{0};` - выделенная память нигде не высвобождается.

Comment: а delete[] mass_char; разве не удалит всю цепочку? или правильно делать в цикле? а насчет "увеличиваете значение указателя mass_char[i] на 0" Вы ошибаетесь, запустите код и проверьте с и без строки.

Comment: "а `delete[] mass_char;` разве не удалит всю цепочку?", нет, это только удалит массив `mass_char`, а удаления массивов, созданных конструкцией `mass_char[i] = new char[3]{0};` не произойдёт. `mass_char` имеет тип "указатель на (указатель на `char`)", соответственно `mass_char[i]` - это просто "указатель на `char`". Прибавив к указателю целочисленное значение ноль (символьный литерал `\0` имеет тип `char` и равен нулю), Вы получите тот же самый указатель. Никакого добавления нулевого символа в конец не происходит. Так что @AnT всё верно пишет.

Comment: @LuckyGamerTV, если Вы обращаетесь к некоторому пользователю, то добавляйте имя этого пользователя начинающееся с символа @ к своему комментарию, чтобы отправить уведомление этому пользователю, иначе Ваш комментарий может быть не замечен.

Comment: @wololo благодарю

Comment: @AnT - спасибо за замечание, сейчас все перепроверил и Вы были правы, благодарю :) ps. не обращайте внимание на(мой) комментарий выше )))

Comment: @wololo почему-то ошибка вылетает (  `for (int i(0); i < sizeOfByteArray; i++)
  delete[] mass_char[i];
 delete[] mass_char;`

Answer (score 0):

unhexlify можно реализовать через [`std::strtol()`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) (пренебрегая обработкой ошибок):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  char hexstr[] = "68 65 6C 6C 6F", bytes[(sizeof hexstr) / 3 + 1] = {};
  char *p = hexstr, *end = nullptr, *pbyte = bytes;
  for (long byte = std::strtol(p, &end, 16); p != end;
            byte = std::strtol(p, &end, 16)) {
    *pbyte++ = byte;
    p = end;
  }
  std::cout << bytes << std::endl;
}
```

Пример:

```
$ c++ -std=c++11 *.cc && ./a.out
hello
```